# Oracle Import option

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, character, utf

I have a simple question, how exactly do you use the oracle import tool to import a database with the option of automatically resize the column length, so it automatically fits the data before importing the data.

Give you an example: if I have a table TABLE1 that has a column called "comment", comment field length is 250. Since I'm importing TABLE1 from source (which is in western character set) into target database (which is AL-UTF32 character set). Some of the records data will grow, i.e. 1 record's comment field data will grow from 250 into 260 because of the character set conversion.

My question is: how do I import TABLE1, so that target database will automatically change the field "comment" from 250 into the max data field length of this field (after character set conversion grows the data). So I can import TABLE1 with no errors.

What's the import option or command line? Is there a way to know which columns cause data issue?

Thank you

Comment: Is your column defined as 250 bytes or 250 characters? If the latter - and it sounds like it should be - then you shouldn't need to change the size. I don't think you'll see 'growth' going from existing Western data to UTF anyway. And if you did resize in bytes, it would need to be wide enough for any future data, not just what you have now. Are you building the table before importing the data, or is the import creating it?

Comment: The source database, the columns is defined as 250 bytes (not characters). We found that by going from western to UTF, Some data in that columns takes up more than 250 bytes after it is converted, which lead to truncation if not handled.

Import is creating the tables in the target.

Comment: Can you create the tables in advance in the target database, using character semantics instead of byte semantics? Data pump import and legacy import can cope with objects already existing, with appropriate command-line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would build your target table beforehand, with the column widths you need defined at that point. You would then tailor a [sqlldr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm) (SQL Loader) control file to your input format.

Comment: That seems to be the only way to do it.